# Is it possible to render editor tab overlays in a VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm thinking of writing an extension which renders an overlay in the currently open editor window for a user, though I can't seem to find if this is possible without some possible clever API manipulation.

I'd like to render this overlay over the code a person is working on, not in a new tab like the Image Preview API handles.

Comment: the whole decorators are an over/under-lay, you can adjust the VSC code and add your own overlay to the API and submit a PR